# How to disable syncing applications without uninstalling them?

Tags: applications, data-synchronization, ios

When I disable syncing apps with my iPad, iTunes uninstalls all apps. How can I make iTunes not mess with it and leave the apps on it, even if I disable synchronization?

I tried disconnecting immediately after applying, but this doesn't save the changes I made.

---

This also happens to my iPods and iPhones.

Comment: did you uncheck sync apps in app tab?

Comment: What is exactly what you’re trying to do? You can uncheck apps in iTunes -> Applications and they won’t be copied to the iPad/Phone.

Comment: @Am1rr3zA the problem is that if I do that, iTunes uninstalls all apps from my device.

Comment: if you disable that check box it just not sync in future and your install app remain on your ipad. if this not happen it's bug I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could select sync Apps but choose the applications you want in your iPad and uncheck the Automatically sync new apps. With this you will have only the applications that are selected.